# C# write values of combobox to excel rows

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application where a user inputs their name (First and Last name) into a combobox. I have a add button that adds whatever value they type in to the combobox and lists it below. **What i'm trying to do is take the names listed in the combobox and input them into excel in separate rows.** I also have 2 columns in the excel file with "First name" and "Last Name" so the name in the combo box needs to be split.

here is my code for my excel:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\gradsheet.xlsx"))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\gradesheet.xlsx", Properties.Resources.gradesheet);
        }

        // if there is no title selected
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboSelect.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure a category is selected.", "No Subject Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return;
        }


        object oOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbook wBook;


        string myPath = @"C:\gradesheet.xlsx";

        wBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value,

          Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        Excel.Worksheet wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Worksheets[1];

        wBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);//get worksheet number
        wSheet.Name = cboSelect.Text;//define name



        //put name in excel(THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE COMBOBOX ITEMS IN EXCEL)
        excelApp.Cells[8, 1] = firstName;
        excelApp.Cells[8, 2] = lastName;


        //Subject Name to cell
        excelApp.Cells[5, 1] = cboSelect.Text;

        //these are some cleanup calls that I found in another example..
        excelApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = false;
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excelApp.Save();
        excelApp.Quit();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);


        GC.Collect();

        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();



        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to open the gradesheet?", "gradesheet", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string gradesheet = @"C:\gradesheet.xlsx";
            Process.Start(gradesheet);
        }


    }
```

Here is my code that splits the first and last name but im not sure how to make it do it for every item in the combobox:

```
string fullName = cboStudent.Text;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string[] parts = fullName.Split(new string[] { ", " },        StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (parts.Length == 1)
        {
            parts = fullName.Split(' ');
            if (parts.Length == 1)
            {
                lastName = fullName;
                firstName = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lastName = parts[1];
                firstName = parts[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastName = parts[0];
            firstName = parts[1];
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't matter how many posts there are about what a bad idea it is to use com interop to manipulate office docs, there's always somebody still doing it.

Comment: @Brook Why is it, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Brook...Bad idea it may be, but surprisingly easy to program.  It has its downsides, i freely admit, but it also has its high points.

Boundinashes6...What exactly was the question?  Its not clear (to me at least) exactly what you are attempting to accomplish here.

Comment: @Yatrix: Because it requires excel to be installed (and licensed), because it starts up an entirely new instance of excel, because those instances of excel often have trouble getting shut down properly and leave you with a machine that has 15 instances of excel.exe running, and finally, and most importantly, because there are far more lightweight options.  http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/
http://npoi.codeplex.com/
http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: @Nevyn my question is how do i take ALL values in a combobox and output each one into a separate cell in excel. For example, the user inputes 3 names "John Do", "John Smith", and "Chuck Norris". I want those names to go into cells A8, A9, and A10 and so forth for how ever many names they input. Also if possible i need to separate the first and last name with the first name going in column A and second name going in column B.

Comment: @Brook, this is a simple program and is only for my girlfriend who is a teacher. It will (hopefully) help her grade papers faster. I don't require any checks to see if excel is installed or not but I can see the drawbacks of using interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like in your case you want every item in the combobox you so use the the "Items" property on the combobox...

```
foreach (object name in cboStudent.Items)
{
      ...
}
```

If you only want the selected item from a list of items you can use the "SelectedItem" property.

Or...

Since you may want to add each item to a different cell in the workbook you can use the for loop so you have an integer number to use for the cell as well...

```
for (int x = 0; x < comboBox1.Items.Count; x++)
{
    object name = comboBox1.Items[x];

    // Split name here

    excelApp.Cells[8+x, 1] = firstName; 
    excelApp.Cells[8+x, 2] = lastName; 

}
```

Comment: Correct, I want all items in the combo box but how do I send each of those into their own rows ? I think i need something like excel.range or something like that.

Comment: @ gene S, Your second loop works however, it is only adding the currently selected item to every cell and not each one separately.

Comment: OK my problem is now with the split code i'm using in the 2nd code box of my original question. It is only grabbing the name of the currently selected item in the combo box and splitting ONLY that. I need it to split every name in the combobox.

Comment: Do you know a way to make all items in the combobox split instead of using just 
        string fullname = cboStudent.text;

Answer (score 1):

OK i solved it here is the code, Thanks for your help guys !

```
//Student Names
        for (int x = 0; x < cboStudent.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                string fullName = cboStudent.Items[x] as string;
                string firstName;
                string lastName;
                string[] parts = fullName.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (parts.Length == 1)
                {
                    parts = fullName.Split(' ');
                    if (parts.Length == 1)
                    {
                        lastName = fullName;
                        firstName = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastName = parts[1];
                        firstName = parts[0];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lastName = parts[0];
                    firstName = parts[1];
                }
                excelApp.Cells[8 + x, 1] = firstName;
                excelApp.Cells[8 + x, 2] = lastName;
            }
```